# CALM Query to get a specifc day and month from any year

Tags: sharepoint

I'd like to create a CALM query to get days and months of any year. Example:

In a list with the results below, I'd like to get all dates that have day equals 10 and month equals 07:

- 07/10/1984
- 01/02/2001
- 05/12/1991
- 07/10/2007

So, the result would be:

- 07/10/1984
- 07/10/2007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to do it directly in CAML for any year so you would end up listing out that day and month range for every year - bit of a monster.

Are you able to add extra calculated columns to your list? If so then you can add

```
DayAndMonth = Day([YourDate]) & "-" & Month([YourDate])
```

Then its a simple case of filtering using CAML or normal view filter (assuming US date format)

```
DayAndMonth = "7-10"
```

Comment: I had already thought it before and unfortunately it seems to be the only way to do this kind of query. Thank you for the help.